# Can Jsch exec 3rd party linux shell?

Tags: java, jsch

I have successfully used jsch to execute linux system shell like "ls;pwd". Now I want to know can Jsch execute some 3rd party linux shell like "clish"?

Comment: Did you try it and what happened ?

Comment: I tried "clish" command but the server only feedback "can't startup clish". But I execute the command in the linux terminal it work well.

Comment: Maybe you could try to use full path of clish because jsch do not load your profile or bashrc files.

Comment: I have added "source /etc/profile;source ~/.bash_profile;" in front of the command but still not work.

Comment: What happens if you use full path of clish ? (`type clish` in a Linux terminal give it). BTW what is your sshd ?

Comment: If I type clish in a linux terminal, everything is ok. I have added full path of clish in my code like "/usr/bin/clish" but still not ok. What do you mean my sshd? The sshd_config?

Comment: I suppose it should be OpenSSH sshd. There is no reason for sshd to reject a command ... except if it was specialy configured. When you use a terminal, are you connected through ssh ?

Comment: yes, connected through ssh. In addition, If I change the inputStream to "System.in", and type the command in the eclipse console, it can work. And the interface is the same as I am working in a linux terminal.

Comment: Please show your source ...

Comment: you mean the source code?

Comment: Yes, Jsch should allow you to execute any command, so should sshd. Please show how you use Jsch.

Comment: JSch jsch=new JSch();
String host = "host";
String user= "user";
Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
session.setPassword("pass");

session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

//session.connect();
session.connect(30000); 

Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");

ByteArrayInputStream bi = new ByteArrayInputStream("clish -e -w \'global-conf-view\' -c \'nest mate\'\n".getBytes());
channel.setInputStream(bi);

channel.setOutputStream(System.out);

channel.connect(3000);

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to line feed, so the code seems messy

Comment: Not a problem, but it would have been simpler to edit your post ... What is the output of the command ?

Comment: the output of the command is "can't startup clish".

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see why Jsch could refuse to execute a command. In my tests any command (only cli command and not XWindow !) work perfectly. I could even launch `vi` (with ugly output of course ...), exit from it properly and logout from shell with `^D`.

The only problem I could identify is timing. Jsch is like any other bedirectionnal tool : it allows you to write and read, but you have to wait that the command has finished its output to read and of course to close the channel. If not, you will find an empty output (or only the login banner), and close communication before the command on server have even begun.

That would explain why it works when you connect the inputStream to `System.in` because then, you wait for the output of one command to type the following.

You can try to add delays in your code to confirm it.

Comment: I have added some delays like "Timer timer = new Timer();
         timer.schedule(new MyTask(), 1000, 2000);" after the "channel.connect()". But the result still is "can't startup clish"

Comment: Just an idea, when you use `System.in` as input, how do you type exactly the `clish` command ? With all the `'` and `\ ` ?

Comment: no, when I use System.in as input, I directly type the command "clish -e -w 'global-conf-view' -c 'nest mate'"(ignore the "") in the console. And it work well.

Comment: Now I can understand ... In fact, Jsch in `shell` channel simply opens a ssh communication, and all happens exactly like if you typed directly in a terminal. Try to remove the `\ ` and write `... = new ByteArrayInputStream("clish -e -w 'global-conf-view' -c 'nest mate'\n".getBytes());`

Comment: well, the fact is, if I remove the \, the result still is "can't startup clish"....

Comment: Is the echo of the command **exactly the same** between that way and typing in System.in ? There is no reason that it is rejected when using Jsch ...

Comment: well, I simply use the command 'clish', just like ... = new ByteArrayInputStream("clish\n".getBytes()); the result still is "can't startup clish", it is so strange...